# Google play leader board player profile not public Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am using google play services to create a leader board and it worked fine for me and testers, but this week i released my game to the play store and got 90+ downloads but only 2 users was added to the leaderboard.

It looks like in "google play games" there is a setting for "public gamer profile" which by default is set to false and that prevents the players from being able to be added to the leaderboard.

Is there any walk arounds?

Or a way to tell if the profile is not public to warn the player?

Or a way to ask them to set it inside the game?

Comment: Have you published your Google Play Games project on the console? If not, it will only work for testers. However players can decide to play without access to Google Play Games, so it may be possible that less than 2% of players have added a score in the leaderboard

Comment: Yes I published it on the console. I already have real users right now. But the number is insufficient. Although I have reached nearly 200 downloads, there are 13 14 scores. I'm sure the problem is caused by this.

Comment: Are you sure that your app always shows the possibility to log in to the GPG? I mean, can all players access the leaderboard? Does your app show access and saving of the score only under certain conditions?

Comment: Every user who makes his profile public can share his score and see others. Apart from this, there is no situation that prevents users from reaching the scoreboard. You can try it yourself if you want.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.CocktailStudios.QuickBrain

Comment: Ok, I've tried, nice game. There is no explicit login prompt, however my score has been stored after I click on the leaderboard button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yes I can see your score. But as you can see, there are only 15 people out of 300 downloads. I think there are users not public in the profile section on Google Play Games. Can I change this in game?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221411/discussion-between-vinserello-and-omer-faruk-geysoglu).

Comment: So is there a solution to this problem?